# Slideshow with bootsrap collapse and tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to make a slideshow with Bootstrap's JavaScript collapse and tab. The idea is to have a list of thumbnails that can be clicked to show a blow up of the picture in a collapse.

I want to be able to click on the first thumbnail to open up the collapse with the first thumbnails blown up pic. When the second thumbnail is clicked, the first blown up pic should be replaced with the second one.

The problem I'm running into right now is that the blown up images are showing up in a list on top of each other instead of replacing each other.

Here is a fiddle with the current issue: http://jsfiddle.net/g7nrt9b4/

Code for the Fiddle:

```
<div class="panel-body">
  <ul class="thumb-list">
    <li><a href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseA1" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseA1"><img class="thumb-img" src="http://www.trbimg.com/img-530546b6/turbine/la-fi-imgur-20140219" alt="temp img" /></a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseA1" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseA1"><img class="thumb-img" src="http://www.trbimg.com/img-530546b6/turbine/la-fi-imgur-20140219" alt="temp img" /></a></li>
  </ul>

  <div class="collapse pic-theater" id="collapseA1">
    <img class="theater-img" src="http://www.trbimg.com/img-530546b6/turbine/la-fi-imgur-20140219" alt="temp img" />
  </div>
  <div class="collapse pic-theater" id="collapseA2">
    <img class="theater-img" src="http://www.trbimg.com/img-530546b6/turbine/la-fi-imgur-20140219" alt="temp img" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There's only HTML code. You have to write some javascript to make this to work. Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

1. Add some class (`show-img` in the example below) to your `img` tags, so you can append a `click` event to them.
2. Add some image loading indicator to inform the user that something is going on when thumbnail is clicked (used [blockUI](http://malsup.com/jquery/block/) just for example).

And we're ready to go:

**HTML**:

```
<div class="panel panel-primary">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title">
            Title.
        </h3>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <ul class="thumb-list">
            <li><a href="#" class="show-img"><img class="thumb-img" src="http://www.trbimg.com/img-530546b6/turbine/la-fi-imgur-20140219" alt="temp img" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="show-img"><img class="thumb-img" src="http://www.trbimg.com/img-530546b6/turbine/la-fi-imgur-20140219" alt="temp img" /></a></li>
            <!-- more images ... -->
        </ul>

        <div id="collapse" class="collapse pic-theater">
            <div class="block">
                <img class="theater-img" src="http://www.trbimg.com/img-530546b6/turbine/la-fi-imgur-20140219" alt="temp img" />
            </div>
        </div>


    </div>
</div>
<img src="https://amitchandnz.files.wordpress.com/2010/08/please_wait.gif?w=614"  id="spinner" />
```

**jQuery**:

```
// don't want to reload current image if it has been already loaded, so make variable for that:
var loaded = false,
    // lastclicked is the item that was last clikced. This is just a variable now, so we do not have to repeat 'var':
    lastClicked,
    // set the collapse element as variable, so we have easir to call it later on:
    collapseEl = $('#collapse');

// method that specify what should happen when the thumbnail is clicked:
$('.show-img').click( function(){
    // class 'current' is to define if the thumbnail was clicked as last, if so, collapse the panel, if not, load image of the thumbnail that was just clicked
    $('.thumb-img').removeClass('current');
    $(this).find('.thumb-img').addClass('current');        
    if(this != lastClicked){
        // the thumbnail wasn't clicked last time:
        lastClicked = this;
        loaded = false;
    }else{
        // the thumbnail was clicked last time, so we want to collapse the panel instead of reloading image again:   
        collapseEl.collapse('toggle');
        loaded = true;
    }
    if(!loaded){
        // show the panel as there's another item loaded inside:
        collapseEl.collapse('show');
        // set that this item is being loaded: 
        loaded = true;
        // fetch the image source from the thumbnail 'href' attribute:
        var img = $(this).find('.thumb-img').attr('src');
        // notify the user that something is going on while loading the image:
        $('.block').block({
            message : $('#spinner'), 
            css : {
                background : 'none', 
                border : 'none'
            }
        }); 
        // load the image:
        $('.theater-img').load( function(){
            // set image as loaded, so the click would not repeat loading process (could be skipped if the images are cached):
            loaded = false;
            // remove loading indicator:
            $('.block').unblock();
            // added [ '?'+ (new Date).getTime() ] - to simulate different images. So each new (except the one that has a 'current' class) thumbnail click tends like it's a new image:
        }).attr('src', img + '?'+ (new Date).getTime());
    }

});

// when panel is collapsed, remove class 'current' from the img, so that we know it's not displayed:
collapseEl.on('hide.bs.collapse', function () {
  $('.thumb-img').removeClass('current');
})
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/5nmaL3d5/1/)